# In Mercurial (hg), how do you see a list of files that will be pushed if an "hg push" is issued?

Tags: mercurial, push, dvcs

We can see all the changesets and the files involved using

```
hg outgoing -v
```

but the filenames are all scattered in the list of changesets.

Is there a way to just see a list of all the files that will go out if `hg push` is issued?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, create a file with this content:

```
changeset = "{files}"
file = "{file}\n"
```

Let's say you call it out-style.txt and put it in your home directory.  Then you can give this command:

```
hg -q outgoing --style ~/out-style.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: great thanks!  wow... this is not often needed that there is no standard way to list all files that will be pushed?  I mean, isn't it useful to see something like that before we do a push?  For example, right now, when I do "hg out -v", I see a list of 20 changesets and individual file and file lists... and I have to mentally combine the names...  and this is a Ruby on Rails project where there are tons of files.

Comment: I guess it all depends on how you work.  At the end of each day, I just push when anything is outgoing.  I don't need to know which changesets or files will be pushed.

Comment: Agreed with JWWalker, it's really not something you're normally concerned about.  However it seems like it would be a trivial extension to write if you really wanted the functionality more easily.

Comment: the reason was that, back in the SVN days, before I commit to the central repository, I will diff every file, re-read the changes I made, line by line and character by character, before I really commit and do a push to all the production servers.  Some of my coworkers just go play video games with the CTO instead, and they actually get a better performance reviews even if they break the whole system sometimes, as they are "good buddies" of the CTO.

Comment: by the way, you can push every day?  Is that push to the live server each day?  Or do you push to a server first and every few days or 1 or 2 weeks, push to the production servers?

Answer (score 7):

A somewhat under-appreciated feature: `hg status` can show information about changes in file status between arbitrary changesets. This can be used to get a list of files changed between revisions `X` and `Y`:

```
hg status --rev X:Y
```

In this case, we can use `hg outgoing`, to find the first outgoing changeset `X` and then do

```
hg status --rev X:
```

to see the files changes since revision `X`. You can combine this into a single line in your shell:

```
hg status --rev $(hg outgoing -q --template '{node}' -l 1):
```

Comment: i thought "hg status" is between working directory and local repository, while "hg outgoing" is between 2 repositories?

Comment: Yes -- 99% of the time, you use `hg status` to show the differences between the parent revision of the working copy and the working copy itself. But you can ask for the file status between any two revisions. So above I simply use `hg outgoing` to learn about the first outgoing changeset and then ask `hg status` to show changes from that changeset.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use

```
hg outgoing -v | grep files
```

It makes the listing shorter, but doesnt sort. But thus far I havent been in a situation where I want to push so much (and at the same time check the files) that its been a problem.

**[Edit]**
To do what you want:

- Use `cut` to remove the `files:` part
- For changesets with more than one touched file, use `tr` to put them on separate lines
- Finally sort the resulting output with `sort`

Like so:

```
hg outgoing -v |grep files: |cut -c 14- |tr ' ' '\n' |sort -u
```

You can put this in *~/outgoingfiles.sh* or something to have it nice and ready.

Comment: That method has the disadvantage that file names within a changeset are separated by spaces.  If you have any file names that contain spaces, then there is no way to automatically separate the file names before sorting.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Torgoise Hg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), which is a shell extension that has a "synchronize" view allowing you to see outgoing files before you push them. It's convenient for commits as well, and other things.

Comment: My preferred way as well, when Im not stuck in a console.

Comment: I use a Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard on it... seems like the Windows guys have TortouseHg but the Mac guys are stuck with the command line!

Comment: Jian Lin: see MacHg for a graphical Mercurial client: http://jasonfharris.com/machg/  I don't know if it can show you a list of outgoing files, though.

Answer (score -1):

A simple `hg out` will also solve this.
It will list all committed but yet to push checkins.

Comment: I am not sure this actually answers the question: since the question deals with the *files* that changed.